# which of the following series convergent

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of real number such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^2$ is convergent. Which of the following statements are correct

a. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n}$ is convergent

b. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^p$ is convergent for all $2<p<\infty$

c. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|^p$ is convergent for all $1<p<2$

By Cauchy Schwarz inequality, first one is clearly convergent. Help me about b and c.

Comment: Note that $|a_n|<1$ for $n$ large as the series $\sum |a_n|^2$ converges. Then $|a_n|^p < |a_n|^2$ for $n$ large, if $p >2$.

Comment: c) Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^{0.5+\delta}}$ where $\delta$ is small positive.

Answer (score 0):

You have that $a_n$ will eventually be less than one and then $|a_n|^p$ will be less than $a_n^2$ which will mean that $\sum |a_n|^p$ converges.

The (c) might converge, but it's not guaranteed by the premisses. Let for example $a_n = n^{-2/3}$ and $p = 3/2$, then $|a_n|^p=1/n$ which means non-convergent series, but $|a_n|^2 = n^{-4/3}$ which means a convergent series.